# Reload DATATABLE inside AJAX success without refreshing page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel, datatables

I have a table using `Datatable` plugin. I have filtered what I want to delete and after deletion, I manage to empty the value.

After that, if I want to filter using the same text again, for example, I have `ba 1` and `ba 2` and after deleting `ba 1`, it still shows the cell when I entered `ba` on the filter textarea field. It suppose to display the remaining `ba` which are not deleted yet.

For your information, I'm not using built in `Datatable Ajax` method.

what I'm trying to do is I want it to reload the table with the new data without refreshing the page after `ajax on success`. How to do that?

My datatable :

```
var table1 = $('#table1').DataTable(
            {                    
                pageLength : 500,      
                lengthChange: false,
                deferRender: true,
                scrollY:  800,
                scrollCollapse: true,
                scrollX: true,
                bSort: false,
                cache: true,
                autoWidth: false,
                columnDefs: [
                    {
                        targets: 0,                            
                        checkboxes: 
                        {
                            selectRow: true
                        }
                    }
                ],
                select: {
                    style: 'multi',
                    selector: 'td:not(:nth-child(4), :nth-child(5), :nth-child(6), :nth-child(9), :nth-child(10), :nth-child(13), :nth-child(14), :nth-child(15), :nth-child(16), :nth-child(17), :nth-child(18), :nth-child(19), :nth-child(20), :nth-child(21), :nth-child(22), :nth-child(23), :nth-child(24), :nth-child(25))'

                }
            });
```

Here's my filtering function code :

```
table1.columns().every(function () 
{
   var table = this;
   $('.filter', this.header()).on('keyup change', delay(function (settings, data, dataIndex) 
   {
      if (table.search() !== this.value) 
      {
         table.search(this.value).draw();
      }
   }, 500));
});
```

Here's my AJAX success code for deletion based on selected checkbox:

```
$('.btnN2').click(function(){
   var answer = confirm('Delete N2 : Are you sure you want to delete selected items?');
   if (answer)
   {
      console.log('yes');
      var rows = $(table1.rows({selected: true}).$('input[type="checkbox"]').map(function()
      {
         return $(this).prop("checked") ? $(this).closest('tr').attr('data-getstockcode') : null;
      }));

      var getstockcodes = [];

      $.each(rows, function(index, rowId) 
      {
         console.log(rowId) 
         getstockcodes.push(rowId);
      });

      $.ajax({
         url: 'del_n2',
         type: 'GET',
         data: {"getstockcodes": JSON.stringify(getstockcodes)},
         dataType: 'JSON',
         success:function(data){                                 
            console.log(data);
            $(table1.rows({selected: true}).$('input[type="checkbox"]').map(function()
            {
               if($(this).prop("checked"))
               {
                  $(this).parents("tr:eq(0)").find(".note2").val('');                                                                                                                       
                  console.log('reset');
               }
            }));
         }
      });
   }
   else
   {
      console.log('cancel');
   }
});
```

Here's my insert data based on keyup event

```
$(".note2").keyup(delay(function()
{  
   var stockcode = $(this).data("stockcode");
   var stockname = $(this).data("stockname");
   var value = $(this).val().replace(/(\r\n|\n)/g, "\\n");

   $.ajax({
      url: 'saveNote2',
      type: 'GET',
      data: 'stockcode='+stockcode+'&stockname='+stockname+'&value='+value,
      dataType: 'JSON',
      success: function(data){                  
         console.log(data);
      },
      error: function(data){                        
         console.log(data);
      }
   });
}, 300));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this in your success function

```
table1.ajax.reload()
```

If you are using ajax datatable or local you need to make it like this

```
  table1.clear(); 
  table1.rows.add(your response data array); 
  table1.draw()
```

Comment: for `table1.ajax.reload()` , it gives me an error saying undefined because I'm not using ajax to load up the table. I'm using laravel controller to query data from db and then return it to view blade ( `index.blade.php` ).

Comment: For `table.rows.add()`, what should I put inside the bracket? If I put `clear();` on my success ajax, it will clear all the field. I don't want that. I just want to update the selected field value when it changes on certain event without loading the whole page. Do you understand what I'm trying to accomplish here? Sorry for my bad english.